# How to refresh cache without restarting server using java

Tags: java, oracle11g

We used `DatabaseChangeNotification(DCN)` to refresh cache but if we migrate to another database we need to change logic. So is there any approach to refresh the cache using java without database dependency?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest don't prefer cache as it causes maintenance cost and time.

Comment: client asking to use cache.so we need to implement cache.is there any approch??